# Trying to Write Javascript to Loop Through YouTube iFrame Embeds

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, iframe, youtube

I'm trying and failing to write a drop-in YouTube embed player for my users, so that they only have to change one line to change any and all YouTube players on a page. I am dropping this into my page, but nothing is happening.

```
        <script>
        // Replace line below with video id(s), e.g. ["dQw4w9WgXcQ"] or ["dQw4w9WgXcQ","b1WWpKEPdT4"]
        var ids = ["dQw4w9WgXcQ","b1WWpKEPdT4"];
        //
        //
        var idsAmount = ids.length;
        for (var i in idsAmount) {
            document.write("<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + ids[i] + "?modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1\" /> <br />");
        };
        </script>
```

No errors in the console. Any idea why nothing happens?

**Edit**: Here is my final working code:

```
        <script>
            // Replace line below with video id(s), e.g. ["dQw4w9WgXcQ"] or ["dQw4w9WgXcQ","b1WWpKEPdT4"]
            var ids = ["dQw4w9WgXcQ","b1WWpKEPdT4"];
            //
            if (ids.length == 1) {
                document.write("<iframe width=\"640px\" height=\"360px\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + ids + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");
                document.write("<br />");
            }
            else {
                for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                    document.write("<iframe width=\"640px\" height=\"360px\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + ids[i] + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");
                    document.write("<br /> <br />");
                };
            };
        </script>
```

Comment: Have you verified the iframe src being generated. Looks like you are escaping a `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are escaping 2 quotes that are not needed to be escaped (for concatenation), also, the loop was wrong, should be as follows:

```
<script>
    // Replace line below with video id(s), e.g. ["dQw4w9WgXcQ"] or ["dQw4w9WgXcQ","b1WWpKEPdT4"]
    var ids = ["dQw4w9WgXcQ","b1WWpKEPdT4"];
    //
    //
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        document.write("<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + ids[i] + "?modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1\" /> <br />");
    };
</script>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much! I appreciate it!

Comment: No Problem. Glad to help.

Comment: Hmm. Any idea why only the first video id would show up on the page, and not each one that gets looped through?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `document.write()` and a `for...` loop, I'd suggest simply iterating over the array itself, using `Array.prototype.map()`, to create an array of HTML nodes that itself be iterated over to append those nodes to a document fragment, which in turn can be appended to a specified DOM node:

```js
// Array of video ids:
var ids = ["dQw4w9WgXcQ", "b1WWpKEPdT4"],

  // creating an <iframe> element:
  iframeElement = document.createElement('iframe'),

  // creating a document fragment:
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),

  // an unitialised (undefined) variable for later use:
  clone,

  // iterating over the array of ids, creating a new
  // array using Array.prototype.map():
  html = ids.map(function(currentID) {
    // in the anonymous function the first
    // argument (here: 'currentID') is the
    // current array-element of the array
    // over which we're iterating.

    // cloning the <iframe>:
    var clone = iframeElement.cloneNode();

    // setting the src property of the cloned
    // <iframe>:
    clone.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + currentID + '?modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=0';
    // Note that 'autoplay' has been set to
    // to '0' on principle.

    // returning the modified clone to the array
    // we're creating:
    return clone;

    // iterating over the array returned from
    // Array.prototype.map() and appending each
    // array-element to the document fragment:
  }).forEach(function(iframe) {
    fragment.appendChild(iframe);
  });

// appending the document fragment to the body element:
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bs7uutjn/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`HTMLIFrameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement).
- [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).